# continuous data, Y response not support in the cross_val_score() binary|multiclass for IterativeImputer for BayesianRidge

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, imputation

**Problem Defined, Continuous Challenge**

This new imputer_bayesian_ridge() function is for Iterative Imputer to impute training data. Sending in data frame training data, then immediately get data.values for numpy array variable. This send or passes a training data with many features, and Y response variable. This effort is only seeking to impute on one single feature.

Apparently my continuous data, Y response data, which is price $$$$ continuous data, is not supported in the cross_val_score(interative_imputer, data_array).

So what advise on how to work with continuous data in Y response variable to work with Iterative Imputer and satisfy the cross_val_score for the object 'interativea_imputer'

To support the target type, should I cast my continuous data in Y response variable to binary? No. For this is not a binary classification, so multiclass is more in line. So how to handle price data when it is the response variable?

**Error Received**

ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.

**CODE**

```
   
def imputer_regressor_bay_ridge(data, y):
    data_array = data.values. ##looks OK

    interative_imputer = IterativeImputer(BayesianRidge()). ## runs OK

    interative_imputer_fit = interative_imputer.fit(data_array) ## runs OK

    data_imputed = interative_imputer_fit.transform(data_array) ## runs OK

    cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1) ## runs OK

    scores = cross_val_score(interative_imputer, data_array, y, 
                             scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
    
    return scores, data_imputed
```

**DATA SAMPLE**

```
print(train_data.shape)
data_array = train_data.values
data_array

(1460, 250)
array([[-1.73086488, -0.20803433, -0.20714171, ..., -0.11785113,
         0.4676514 , -0.30599503],
       [-1.7284922 ,  0.40989452, -0.09188637, ..., -0.11785113,
         0.4676514 , -0.30599503],
       [-1.72611953, -0.08444856,  0.07347998, ..., -0.11785113,
         0.4676514 , -0.30599503],
       ...,
       [ 1.72611953, -0.16683907, -0.14781027, ..., -0.11785113,
         0.4676514 , -0.30599503],
       [ 1.7284922 , -0.08444856, -0.08016039, ..., -0.11785113,
         0.4676514 , -0.30599503],
       [ 1.73086488,  0.20391824, -0.05811155, ..., -0.11785113,
         0.4676514 , -0.30599503]])

y = train_data['ResponseY'].values
y.shape  

(1460,)
array([ 0.34727322,  0.00728832,  0.53615372, ...,  1.07761115,
       -0.48852299, -0.42084081])
```

**Value Error**

Apparently my continuous data, which is price $ data, is not supported in  cross_val_score(interative_imputer, data_array on:

ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.

```
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:820, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    819 try:
--> 820     tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    821 except queue.Empty:
    822     # slice the iterator n_jobs * batchsize items at a time. If the
    823     # slice returns less than that, then the current batchsize puts
   (...)
    826     # accordingly to distribute evenly the last items between all
    827     # workers.

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/queue.py:168, in Queue.get(self, block, timeout)
    167     if not self._qsize():
--> 168         raise Empty
    169 elif timeout is None:

Empty: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 5
      3 #train_data, test_data = minmaxscaler(train_data, test_data)  # alternate run for min-max scaler
      4 columns, imputed_df = imputer_regressor(train_data)
----> 5 scores, data_imputed = imputer_regressor_bay_ridge(train_data, y)
      7 misTrain = whichColumnsMissing(train_data)
      8 misTest = whichColumnsMissing(test_data)

Cell In[24], line 110, in imputer_regressor_bay_ridge(data, y)
    108 data_imputed = interative_imputer_fit.transform(data_array)
    109 cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
--> 110 scores = cross_val_score(interative_imputer, data_array, 
    111                          y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
    113 return scores, data_imputed

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:509, in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    506 # To ensure multimetric format is not supported
    507 scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
--> 509 cv_results = cross_validate(
    510     estimator=estimator,
    511     X=X,
    512     y=y,
    513     groups=groups,
    514     scoring={"score": scorer},
    515     cv=cv,
    516     n_jobs=n_jobs,
    517     verbose=verbose,
    518     fit_params=fit_params,
    519     pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
    520     error_score=error_score,
    521 )
    522 return cv_results["test_score"]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:267, in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    264 # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are
    265 # independent, and that it is pickle-able.
    266 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose, pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
--> 267 results = parallel(
    268     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    269         clone(estimator),
    270         X,
    271         y,
    272         scorers,
    273         train,
    274         test,
    275         verbose,
    276         None,
    277         fit_params,
    278         return_train_score=return_train_score,
    279         return_times=True,
    280         return_estimator=return_estimator,
    281         error_score=error_score,
    282     )
    283     for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups)
    284 )
    286 _warn_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    288 # For callabe scoring, the return type is only know after calling. If the
    289 # return type is a dictionary, the error scores can now be inserted with
    290 # the correct key.

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1041, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1032 try:
   1033     # Only set self._iterating to True if at least a batch
   1034     # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
   (...)
   1038     # was very quick and its callback already dispatched all the
   1039     # remaining jobs.
   1040     self._iterating = False
-> 1041     if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1042         self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1044     while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:831, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    828 n_jobs = self._cached_effective_n_jobs
    829 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
--> 831 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    832 if len(islice) == 0:
    833     return False

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:267, in <genexpr>(.0)
    264 # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are
    265 # independent, and that it is pickle-able.
    266 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose, pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
--> 267 results = parallel(
    268     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    269         clone(estimator),
    270         X,
    271         y,
    272         scorers,
    273         train,
    274         test,
    275         verbose,
    276         None,
    277         fit_params,
    278         return_train_score=return_train_score,
    279         return_times=True,
    280         return_estimator=return_estimator,
    281         error_score=error_score,
    282     )
    283     for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups)
    284 )
    286 _warn_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    288 # For callabe scoring, the return type is only know after calling. If the
    289 # return type is a dictionary, the error scores can now be inserted with
    290 # the correct key.

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:1411, in _RepeatedSplits.split(self, X, y, groups)
   1409 for idx in range(n_repeats):
   1410     cv = self.cv(random_state=rng, shuffle=True, **self.cvargs)
-> 1411     for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X, y, groups):
   1412         yield train_index, test_index

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:340, in _BaseKFold.split(self, X, y, groups)
    332 if self.n_splits > n_samples:
    333     raise ValueError(
    334         (
    335             "Cannot have number of splits n_splits={0} greater"
    336             " than the number of samples: n_samples={1}."
    337         ).format(self.n_splits, n_samples)
    338     )
--> 340 for train, test in super().split(X, y, groups):
    341     yield train, test

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:86, in BaseCrossValidator.split(self, X, y, groups)
     84 X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
     85 indices = np.arange(_num_samples(X))
---> 86 for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
     87     train_index = indices[np.logical_not(test_index)]
     88     test_index = indices[test_index]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:709, in StratifiedKFold._iter_test_masks(self, X, y, groups)
    708 def _iter_test_masks(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
--> 709     test_folds = self._make_test_folds(X, y)
    710     for i in range(self.n_splits):
    711         yield test_folds == i

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:652, in StratifiedKFold._make_test_folds(self, X, y)
    650 allowed_target_types = ("binary", "multiclass")
    651 if type_of_target_y not in allowed_target_types:
--> 652     raise ValueError(
    653         "Supported target types are: {}. Got {!r} instead.".format(
    654             allowed_target_types, type_of_target_y
    655         )
    656     )
    658 y = column_or_1d(y)
    660 _, y_idx, y_inv = np.unique(y, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), the use of `scoring='accuracy'` is only for binary or multiclass targets.
You should use instead `scoring=None` or some other scoring adequate for continuous targets. See [regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) ('neg_mean_absolute_error', 'neg_mean_squared_error', ...).

Comment: thanks, in my rush, I completely overlooked the scoring parameters api for None, much appreciated, I will use neg_mean_squared_error